# Eclipse and jre link. Java prog runs without jre link in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I installed java(jdk and jre) along with eclipse.

I was having trouble with launching eclipse(was throwing **jvm not found** kind of error) and hence on googling found that I need to place the **javaw.exe** file inside the eclipse folder or update the vm location in .ini file to the bin folder of the jre.

Eclipse then started working fine.

However just to understand things in deep, I tried to remove the **-vm** location and also the **javaw.exe** file from eclipse folder.

Still I find that the java program in eclipse is running successfully. I was hoping for eclipse to throw the **jvm not found** type of error.

I am fairly new to java/eclipse but my understanding is that only jre is needed for running an existing java program.

Also I remember running java programs from command prompt where setting of environment variables were required. But while working on eclipse so such thing has been done. Is setting of environment variable not needed with eclipse?

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse doesn't use environment variables to decide which JRE to use.

The JRE/JDKs that Eclipse can use to run a Java program are listed in the Preferences in the 'Java > Installed JREs' page.

You choose which JRE to use from the installed JREs list when you create each Java project. You can change the choice in the Properties for the Project on the 'Java Build Path' page.